# Estructura para app iOS

Tags: ios, app

Creando una app para iOS me asalta el siguiente problema de estructura:

La app tendría que estar conectada a una base de datos **mysql** que sirve también como base de datos para web.

Ahora el paso que no se cómo orientar muy bien es cómo realizar: con tu **usuario/contraseña** acceder a tu bd correspondiente (por ejemplo: con datos de usuario **pepe/1234** acceder a la base de datos **empresa1_bd** ; con los datos **alguno/4567** acceder a la base de datos **empresa2_bd**).

¿Tendría que tener una bd intermedia o algo parecido?

Comment: tendrías que tener un backend para facilitarte la vida.

Comment: Perdona @Spidvmp pero ¿a qué te refieres con un backend?

Comment: un servicio web, al cual te conectas, le pass unos parámetros y ese servicio web se ocupa de conectarse a la BD, hacer lo que tenga que hacer y devolverte la información. Conectarte directamente a la BD con un cliente desde iOS no lo veo. Mejor de esta forma. Si de repente tienes que hacer unos cambios de calculo, lo cambias en web y no tienes que volver a hacer una versión nueva de tu app

Comment: Imagino que lo que tienes ahora es un html que cuando le das aceptar en el formulario, habrá por detrás un php, por ejemplo, que coge la información que le has pasado, se conecta y te devuelve la pagina a mostrar, pues algo parecido. El HTML como tal no se conecta a la BD, será el php quien lo haga

Comment: @Spidvmp Si, ahora mismo tengo lo que me comentas. Si paso eso mismo a un backend como me comentas para la conexión tendría que indicar que el usuario con contraseña tal tiene permiso para cierta base de datos en concreto ¿cierto?. Ese mismo backend sería el que me trabajaría con los datos y se los devolvería a la app ¿no?

Comment: Lo que ya tengas para el html, con pocos ca,bios te debería servir para la App. Lo suyo es que sea igual, así que ese back lo haces una ves y te sirve para html, iOS, Android. Tienes que ver como pasas la información para que te sirva en todas las plataformas

Comment: Ahá, hasta ahí todo bien pero ahora la duda que me surge es si las correspondientes bases de datos están en distintos servidores? No sé hasta qué punto sería eso posible realizarlo @Spidvmp

Comment: Pues eso como lo harías en web? pues de la misma forma. Donde estén las Bases de datos te debería dar igual, sera un backend quien se busque la vida para conectarse. Tu desde la app solo iras a una dirección web con unos parámetros por post o get y la respuesta es la que tendrás que mostrar en la app

Comment: Es que estoy empezando en el tema de las apps quizás es una pregunta tonta jaja. Sería una app nativa que se conectaría a un php que recibe usuario/pass y conecta donde deba no? Si no he entendido mal el concepto @Spidvmp